# Test fail using JUnit Selenium WebDriver with xml file

Tags: xml, selenium, junit

I am trying to run cross browser test (reading from xml file) using Junit and i am getting this error:

```
**"java.lang.Exception: Method verifyTitle should have no parameters at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.validatePublicVoidNoArg(FrameworkMethod.java:69) at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(ParentRunner.java:131) at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateTestMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRun"**
```

*XML code:*

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" parallel="tests" >
  <test name="fireFoxTest" >
  <parameter name="browser" value="fireFox"/>
    <classes>
       <class name="crossbrowser.VerifyTitle" />
    </classes>
  </test>
```

Class code:

```
package testCases;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import utility.ConfigReader;

public class VerifyTitle {

    WebDriver driver;
    static ConfigReader config;

    @Test
    @Parameters("browser")

    public void verifyTitle(String browserName) {
if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))

        {
            config = new ConfigReader();

            System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", config.getChromePath());

            System.out.println("========== Setup Ready =========");
        }
```

What could be the reason and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mixing up JUnit and TestNG. If you intended to use **TestNG**, then:

1. Delete

   ```
   import org.junit.Test;
   ```
2. Add instead

   ```
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;
   ```

See full example [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_parameterized_test.htm).

If you intend to use **Junit**, then

1. Delete

   ```
   import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
   ```
2. Add instead

   ```
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
   import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter;
   ```
3. Annotate class this way:

   ```
   @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
   public class VerifyTitle {
   ```
4. Add a member variable called `browserName` and remove a parameter from the function. Annotate that variable and not the function:

   ```
   @Parameter(value = "chrome")
   public String browserName;

   @Test
   public void verifyTitle() {
   ```

See full example [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests)

Answer (score 0):

```
i tried to fix the problem according the steps above but still i encountered failures.

this is what i did:

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import utility.ConfigReader;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class VerifyTitle {

    WebDriver driver;
    static ConfigReader config;

    @Parameter(value = "chrome")
    public String browserName;

    @Test
    public void verifyTitle() {
if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))

        {
            config = new ConfigReader();

            System.setProperty("Webdriver.chrome.driver", config.getChromePath());

            System.out.println("========== Setup Ready =========");
        }
```

The problems i see:

```
1. import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter; ----not recognized
2. java.lang.Exception: No public static parameters method on class testCases.VerifyTitle
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.getParametersMethod(Parameterized.java:163)
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.getParametersList(Parameterized.java:149)
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.<init>(Parameterized.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

Am i missing something else?
Thanks
```

Comment: you should not add comments as solution..you can edit your original question and add your updates there